# TCP retransmission

Tags: http, wireshark

I have an issue to receive a data from my sensor with TCP retransmission message.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/865fL.png)
Any idea please?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9OvcI.png)

Answer (score 0):

The retransmissions that you are seeing are the `SYN` packet.  This indicates that the server to which the packets are being sent is not responding *at all*.

If the server were responding, you would expect to see a `SYN/ACK` indicating that the connection attempt is being accepted or a `RST/ACK` indicating that the connection attempt is being rejected.

From what you have posted, I would look to see what the firewall rules look like on `192.168.0.39`.  I would expect to find that it is silently dropping inbound `SYN` packets on port 55838.

Comment: Thank your for Your replay David Have-you an idea how i could fix it please?

Comment: Have you checked the firewall rules on the server host?

Comment: Yeah but i didn't have SYN packets . see the attached image please

Comment: In your wireshark capture, every retransmission in there is a SYN.

Comment: Hi @emmy, How you can resolve the above issue? Can you please share your thoughts?